# How can I make Django library code visible to VS2022 at develop- and run-time?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Following a Microsoft tutorial for Django, using VS2022, but I have hit what seems to be a simple scope / visibility problem. Intellisense shows references to some Django imports as "unresolvable by source".

The specific error (sample):

1. Import "django.urls" could not be resolved from source

I think it indicates that the Django module is not visible to VS, and that is supported by the fact that the app does actually run OK.  So I think that I have not successfully specified to VS which env it should use during development.

A post from a few years ago suggests that development-time and run-time are using different Python environments, but I have followed the instructions to make sure that the (virtual) env ("env" below) is specified for the project. The project file includes this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Interpreter Include="env">
    <Id>env</Id>
    <Version>3.7</Version>
    <Description>env (Python 3.7 (64-bit))</Description>
    <InterpreterPath>Scripts\python.exe</InterpreterPath>
    <WindowsInterpreterPath>Scripts\pythonw.exe</WindowsInterpreterPath>
    <PathEnvironmentVariable>PYTHONPATH</PathEnvironmentVariable>
    <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
    </Interpreter>
</ItemGroup>
```

Any suggestions welcome.